# Cant pass attribute from iteration to child component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Let's say I have two components. Part of Parent

```
 <aura:iteration items = "{!v.resultSet}" var = "record">
               <tr data-id = "{#record.id}"> 
                   <aura:iteration items = "{#record.data}" var = "field" indexVar="idx">
                        <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-edit slds-cell-container slds-is-resizable" >
                                   <c:soqlField field="{!field}"/>
                                   </td>
                   </aura:iteration>
               </tr>
           </aura:iteration>
```

and c:soqlField component

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name = "field" type = "List"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{#field.fieldType == 'url'}">
            <a href="{#'/' + field.data}">{#field.data}</a>
        <aura:set attribute = "else">
                <div class="slds-truncate" >{#field.data}</div>
        </aura:set>    
        </aura:if>
```

but in runtime i got an error

Uncaught Assertion Failed!: Unable to get value for key 'field.fieldType'. No value provider was found for 'field'. : false

what is wrong in my case? What should I do to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

`#` is for 1 time binding, only the value passed/assigned before UI renders will be shown in UI and any further changes will not reflect in UI, so, it is recommended to use `!` if you want to reflect the changes dynamically. Also you should use `v.` in component.

Below change in ***soqlField*** component should work:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.field.fieldType == 'url'}">
    <a href="{!'/' + v.field.data}">{!v.field.data}</a>
    <aura:set attribute = "else">
        <div class="slds-truncate" >{!v.field.data}</div>
    </aura:set>    
</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `<c:soqlField field="{!field}"/>`
to `<c:soqlField field="{!v.field}"/>` . You are missing the access provider v.

Comment: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

The attribute in the child is of Type List, and the list doesn't have any attribute like `fieldType, data`. See your code below:

```
<aura:attribute name = "field" type = "List"/>
```

So if you are passing the list then you will need to use `aura:iteration`.
If you want to add some extra data with list you can create a wrapper object like

```
{ fieldType: '', data : [] }
```

---

If the data is not of tyle list then you need to change the datatype to Object in child component like below

```
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit changing and everything is okay!

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.field.fieldType == 'url'}">
    <a href="{!'/' + v.field.data}">{!v.field.data}</a>
<aura:set attribute = "else">
    <div class="slds-truncate" >{!v.field.data}</div>
</aura:set>    
</aura:if>
```

Comment: yes, this is what I exactly told, also check the explanations for WHY in [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/285113/70823)